# Proof of functional analysis theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

[image]

Can anyone see why it follows that $\Vert u_{j}-u_{l} \Vert^{2} = 2[\Vert u_{j} \Vert^{2}+ \Vert u_{l} \Vert^{2}] - \Vert u_{j} + u_{l} \Vert^{2} = 2[E(u_{j}) + E(u_{l})] - 4E(\frac{u_{j}+u_{l}}{2})$ in the proof above? Thanks

The link to this document can be found at [PDF location](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~simonl/Nonlinear%20PDE%27s_book_hyperref.pdf)

The theorem is on page 40.

Comment: Can you read what's in that picture?

Comment: @Shaun right click view image!

Comment: @Shaun Yes I can. You have to click on it and go to view image. Can you still not see it?

Comment: It's probably just the computer I'm using then. Sorry, @JohnDoe! :)

Comment: @Shaun No prob. Not sure also, might be your browser(I'm using Firefox). But if most people can't see it then I will type out question.

Comment: Why not adding link to the pdf-file? (The screenshot is not very comfortable to read.) http://www.cs.elte.hu/~simonl/Nonlinear%20PDE%27s_book_hyperref.pdf

Comment: @MartinSleziak Okay I edited the post to include the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality is just the parallelogram identity, valid for all norms arising from an inner product.

Next, for the purported equality

$$2[\Vert u_{j} \Vert^{2}+ \Vert u_{l} \Vert^{2}] - \Vert u_{j} + u_{l} \Vert^{2} = 2[E(u_{j}) + E(u_{l})] - 4E(\frac{u_{j}+u_{l}}{2}),$$

we observe that the linear part of $E$ cancels on the right hand side, so we are left with

$$\begin{align}
2[E(u_{j}) + E(u_{l})] - 4E(\frac{u_{j}+u_{l}}{2})
&= 2\left[\langle Au_j, u_j\rangle + \langle Au_l, u_l\rangle\right] - 4 \left\langle A\frac{u_j+u_l}{2}, \frac{u_j+u_l}{2}\right\rangle\\
&= 2\left[\langle Au_j, u_j\rangle + \langle Au_l, u_l\rangle\right] - \langle A(u_j+u_l), u_j+u_l\rangle\\
&= \left[\langle Au_j, u_j\rangle + \langle Au_l, u_l\rangle\right] - \langle Au_j,u_l\rangle - \langle Au_l,u_j\rangle\\
&= \langle A(u_j-u_l), u_j-u_l\rangle.
\end{align}$$

However, that is generally not equal to $\lVert u_j - u_l\rVert_V^2$.

**But**, $A$ is assumed bounded, self-adjoint, and strictly positive (in the sense that there is a $c > 0$ with $\langle Au,u\rangle \geqslant c\lVert u\rVert^2$ for all $u$, presumably, since that is how "strictly positive is used in remark 2.11").

Therefore $(u \mspace{-3mu}\mid\mspace{-3mu} v) = \langle Au,v\rangle$ is an inner product on $V$ equivalent to the given inner product, and apparently $\lVert u\rVert$ denotes the norm arising from that inner product here (Note that elsewhere, the norm is indexed by the space, $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$ resp. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{V^\star}$).

So then the second equality is just the cancelling of the linear terms $-2\langle F,u\rangle$ on the right hand side.

Since, as noted above, the norms are equivalent, it follows that the minimising sequence $(u_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is indeed a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what property of $A$ allows you to define the new inner product $(u \mid v) = \langle Au,v \rangle$. I know $\langle Au,u \rangle \geq c\Vert u \Vert^{2}$ follows from $A$ assumed strictly positive.

Comment: $\langle Au,v\rangle$ is always bilinear. The symmetry follows from the self-adjointness of $A$, and $(\,\cdot\mid\cdot\,)$ is an inner product if $A$ is positive definite. The strict positivity ($\langle Au,u\rangle \geqslant c\lVert u\rVert_V^2$) guarantees that the norm induced by $(\,\cdot\mid\cdot\,)$ dominates $\lVert\cdot\rVert_V$, and the boundedness of $A$ guarantees the domination in the other direction, so that altogether the two norms are equivalent.

Comment: I just want to confirm the reasoning for the case of symmetry.
The wiki definition of self-adjoint is a linear map from Hilbert space $V$ to itself, say $A: V \rightarrow V$ then $A$ is self-adjoint if $\langle Av,w \rangle_{V} = \langle v,Aw \rangle_{V}$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{V}$ is the inner-product on $V$. In our case we have $A: V \rightarrow V^{*}$, but by Riesz-representation theorem we can show that we can identify(isometrically isomorphic) $V$ and $V^{*}$.

Comment: Further we can consider any $V \times V^{*}$ pairing say $\langle Au,w \rangle$ as the inner product $\langle Au,w \rangle_{V}$ where $Au$ is some unique element in $V$(which exists by Riesz-representation theorem). So we can consider $A: V \rightarrow V^{*}$  as $A:V \rightarrow V$ and then use the definition of self-adjoint as I described above and apply it to $A:V \rightarrow V$ to show the symmetry of the new inner-product $(u \mid v)$.  Is this reasoning fine?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Actually, I think the use of terminology in that text is bad, saying $A\colon V\to V^\ast$ is self-adjoint is an abuse of language that IMO helps nothing. When speaking of $A\colon V\to V^\ast$, one should better say that $A$ is symmetric - that is, $A(u)(v)=A(v)(u)$ for all $u,v$; with the pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\colon V^\ast\times V\to\mathbb{R}$, that becomes $\langle Au,v\rangle=\langle Av,u\rangle$. That makes sense also if $V$ is not a Hilbert space. (Yes, for operators on Hilbert spaces, symmetric also has a different-but-related meaning, but we all are

Comment: familiar with symmetric bilinear forms, and $L(V,V^\ast)$ is canonically isomorphic to $L^2(V)$, the space of (continuous) bilinear forms on $V$.)

Comment: Yes I agree, the use of terminology is a bit confusing. It's probably simpler just stating as you say that $A$ is symmetric or maybe saying that we can derive a self-adjoint operator from $A$. I see you used the notation $(u\mid w)$ when you defined the new scalar product in your answer. What exactly is the standard use of this notation, I see they use it when defining a symmetric operator in the wiki entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator).

Comment: There is no standard use of notation when it comes to inner products. People use $(\cdot,\cdot)$, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, $(\cdot\mspace{-2mu}\mid\mspace{-2mu}\cdot)$, $\langle \cdot\mspace{-2mu}\mid\mspace{-2mu}\cdot\rangle$, $x\cdot y$, $xy$, and lots of other notations, probably. If you are lucky, people distinguish between different inner products when using several at the same time, but not all do that. I just took $(\cdot\mspace{-2mu}\mid\mspace{-2mu}\cdot)$ to avoid any possible confusion with $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ here.

Comment: Heh, on that wikipedia page, in the introduction, they use $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ for the inner product, and in the body, they use $\langle\cdot\mspace{-2mu}\mid\mspace{-2mu}\cdot\rangle$. As I said, no standard, and consistency is difficult to maintain when several authors are involved. Yes, just the ordinary inner product that is given on the space.

Comment: Okay thanks, I understand. One would hope for consistency, at least on the same page :)